# Inner product structure on geometric algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, multilinear-algebra, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

I understand that geometric algebra equips itself with the contraction operators $\rfloor$ and $\lfloor$. While these are awesome when one wishes to project a subspace onto another, it is *not* an inner product structure anymore.

What I am looking for is some analogue of the inner product. An operator $\star: G \times G \rightarrow \mathbb R$ which is bilinear, symmetric, and non-degenerate.

Does such an operator exist over a geometric algebra?

1. If it does, can we assign some nice geometric meaning to it? (I would like something along the lines of "measure of mutual containment" or some such)
2. If we *cannot* define such an operator $\star$, what is the obstacle?

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra) is something said about products.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Indeed, there are plethora of products there (inner, outer, geometric), but none of them have the signature I ask for. All of them can spit out values that are larger than scalars

Comment: Seeking to define a structure and then assigning meaning to it is putting the cart before the horse.  If you've studied geometric/Clifford algebra for any amount of time, you'll know it leverages the theory of inner product spaces by "building in" the inner product into the algebra product. It is not clear how defining an inner product on the entire algebra is going to be useful.  Maybe you should take a look at [this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-009-3713-0_14) and you might see something you're looking for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure any nondegenerate form on a finite dimensional space is going to give you a semisimple ring, which is automatically a von Neumann algebra, and it appears those all have inner products compatible with the algebra operations, so that is one thing.

Comment: It seems like the natural candidate for developing an inner product to detect "degree of containment" would be to work with the wedge product in the geometric algebra, since that already gives an indicator of containment.

Comment: What did you make of the product labeled "the scalar product" [in the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra#Extensions_of_the_inner_and_exterior_products)?

Comment: @rschwieb : Unfortunately, the wedge product does not work, since I need an actual _measure_ of containment, in the sense of a real number I can optimise on. I'm phrasing a nonlinear optimisation problem in terms of geometric algebra's constructs for which I need a value to maximise on.

Comment: @SiddharthBhat I know the wedge product doesn't *directly* work but I'm saying it's an obvious candidate to adapt (say, by composing with a linear functional) to produce something that does work.

Comment: @rschwieb ah , interesting, I missed that one :) however, the page covers no geometric meaning of that product. Can you tell me what it is?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat I have no idea. I'd just start searching, e.g. for something [like this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.5935.pdf) and other resources.

Comment: @rschwieb: thanks a ton! This was great :)

Comment: And, as always, it bears repeating since some people don't seem to be aware: not everything has geometric significance.

Comment: Indeed, but I would hope a building block of _geometric_ algebra would have some geometric significance ;)

Comment: There's a paper titled [The Inner Products of Geometric Algebra](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-0089-5_2) that goes over several variations on possible inner-product-like operations.

Comment: @rschwieb I've been reading the GA notes you linked, and I managed to finally get a computational definition of the scalar product: As far as I can tell, all it appears to do is to take a "dot product" of two elements of the geometric algebra by multiplying their components together. This is disappointing, since it does nothing to deal with objects that are contained within one another.

Comment: Btw, if you are trying to optimize on something that is not purely numerical, but is of the form scalar $\cdot$ "thing" (for a fixed choice of thing, like basis vector for the highest non-vanishing exterior power), you can still optimize on the scalar coefficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The natural inner product is

$$A\star B=\langle A^\sim B\rangle_0=\langle A\,B^\sim\rangle_0=\langle B^\sim A\rangle_0=\langle B\,A^\sim\rangle_0$$

$$=\langle A^\sim\bullet B\rangle_0=\langle A^\sim\,\lrcorner\,B\rangle_0=\langle A^\sim\,\llcorner\, B\rangle_0,$$

the scalar part of the geometric product (or any of [these four products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra#Extensions_of_the_inner_and_exterior_products)), with one factor reversed. This is analogous to the Frobenius inner product of matrices, $\text{tr}(A^TB)$. It's the familiar sum of products of corresponding components, with respect to a standard orthonormal basis $\{1,e_1,e_2,e_1e_2,e_3,e_1e_3,e_2e_3,e_1e_2e_3,\cdots\}$. For example in 2D,

$$(\alpha+\alpha_1e_1+\alpha_2e_2+\alpha_{12}e_1e_2)\star(\beta+\beta_1e_1+\beta_2e_2+\beta_{12}e_1e_2)=\alpha\beta+\alpha_1\beta_1+\alpha_2\beta_2+\alpha_{12}\beta_{12}.$$

Terms of different grade are orthogonal. Terms of the same grade have inner product

$$(a_1\wedge a_2\wedge\cdots\wedge a_k)\star(b_1\wedge b_2\wedge\cdots\wedge b_k)=(a_k\wedge\cdots\wedge a_2\wedge a_1)\bullet(b_1\wedge b_2\wedge\cdots\wedge b_k)$$

$$=\det[a_i\cdot b_j].$$

(I'm assuming that the underlying vector space has an inner product; then $\star$ is also an inner product. But this $\star$ extends any symmetric bilinear form on the vector space to the whole algebra, regardless of positive-definiteness or non-degeneracy.)