# Geometric Algebra: getting the geometric interpretation of $k$-blades

Tags: exterior-algebra, geometric-algebras

I'm approaching "Geometric Algebra for Computer Science" coming from "Abastract algebra" by Dummit and Foote. I learned exterior algebra, from an abstract point of view, as quotient of the tensor algebra. Now I'm facing some difficoulties getting a full understanding of the proposed practical and succint treatment.

How exactly the k-blades $a_1\wedge \dots \wedge a_k$ gets associated with its attitude, orientation and weight, as an element of $\bigwedge \mathbb{R}^n$ and how these attributes depends on $n$?

The book says that the attitude is the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ spanned by $a_1, ..., a_k$, and that seems enough to me. Then it only defines orientation and weight for the case $n=k=2$ or $n=k=3$ saying also that orientation has not a complete generalization for all the cases, namely, for every $k,n$. The weight is the determinant of the matrix with $a1,..,a_k$ as columns.

One particular thing that I have been asking is: how can I calculate the weight of $a_1 \wedge a_2$ in the case $k=2, n=3$. Here the matrix with column $a_1, a_2$ is not squared thus it has not a determinant but the concept of area for a 2-D surface still makes sense. I guess I need some projection into the subspace, do I?

Comment: "geometric algebra" is a bastardised mashup of Clifford algebras and exterior algebras. You really need to swot up on Clifford algebras before looking at geometric algebra.

Comment: @AnginaSeng thank you. Have you some introductory texts on Clifford algebras to suggest?

Comment: There's the text by Garling (CUP), which I haven't  read...

Comment: @AnginaSeng thanks, I'll take a look.

Comment: The weight of a multivector is its norm, $\lVert A\rVert=\sqrt{\langle A^\sim\,A\rangle_0}$. See my answer on [extending inner products](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3320392/472818). In particular, $\lVert a\wedge b\rVert=\sqrt{(a\cdot a)(b\cdot b)-(a\cdot b)^2}$.

Comment: I think that you do not need to study Clifford algebras before geometric algebra. The wording "a bastardised mashup of Clifford algebras and exterior algebras" might indicate a bias against or ignorance of geometric algebra.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I don't think geometric algebra is a mashup of clifford algebras with anything. It's more like a special case of clifford algebras, perhaps treated from a certain perspective/with certain goals. [The real numbers section of the English Wikipedia page for "Clifford Algebra"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra#Real_numbers) essentially makes this claim.

Comment: @MarkS. When I talked about a "bastardised mashup", I was being overly polite.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Regardless of your opinion of geometric algebra - I was disagreeing with the *factual* claim of it being a "mashup". It seems analogous to calling the complex numbers "a mashup of algebras over the reals and the direct sum of the additive group of $\mathbb R$ with itself". Those are certainly related concepts, but I wouldn't call it a mashup.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Amazon preview of the book “[Geometric Algebra for Computer Science (Revised Edition): An Object-Oriented Approach to Geometry](http://www.geometricalgebra.net/)” by Leo Dorst, Daniel Fontijne, and Stephen Mann (GACS), it seems like an answer to your questions
(as well as a potential error that led to [the OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/444892/giovanni-barbarani)'s confusion) can be found
in sections 2.8 and 3.1.

Another reference for an introduction to geometric algebra is “[Linear and Geometric Algebra](http://www.faculty.luther.edu/%7Emacdonal/laga/)” (LaGA) by [MSE's own Alan Macdonald](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/32632/alan-macdonald).

#### Attitude

In the table referenced in 2.8.2 of GACS, they write that the attitude
of a blade $\mathbf{A}$ is “The equivalence class $\lambda\mathbf{A}$,
for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$”. That should probably not allow
$\lambda=0$, but it is good to think of the attitude as defined in
[the OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3782180/26369): “the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ spanned by $a_{1},\ldots,a_{k}$”.
Section 6.2 of LaGA says “A blade and a nonzero scalar multiple
of it (another blade) represent the same subspace.”

#### Weight (and Norm)

In the table referenced in 2.8.2 of GACS, they write that the (relative)
weight is “The value of $\lambda$ in $\mathbf{A}=\lambda\mathbf{I}$
(where $\mathbf{I}$ is a selected standard subspace with the same
attitude)”. So “relative weight” can be positive or negative,
and depends crucially on the choice of another blade $\mathbf{I}$
with the same attitude. This definition seems to throw out any absolute
sense of scale - if $\mathbf{I}_{1}$ is one choice giving a certain
relative weight $\lambda_{1}$ for $\mathbf{A}$, then it seems that
$\mathbf{I}_{2}=2\mathbf{I}_{1}$ would give a new weight $\lambda_{2}=\lambda_{1}/2$.
But I am not sure whether that was intended.

In 3.1.3 of GACS, they write “[the norm of a blade] indeed gives
us a sensible geometric measure of the weight of the subspace represented
by the blade, as an area or (hyper)volume”. So it seems, at the
very least, that GACS supports a definition of “(absolute) weight”
being the norm $\left\Vert \mathbf{A}\right\Vert $. It is defined in 3.1.3
by
$$
\left\Vert \mathbf{a}_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathbf{a}_{k}\right\Vert ^{2}
$$

$$
=\left(\mathbf{a}_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathbf{a}_{k}\right)*\widetilde{\left(\mathbf{a}_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathbf{a}_{k}\right)}
$$

$$
=\left(\mathbf{a}_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathbf{a}_{k}\right)*\left(\mathbf{a}_{k}\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathbf{a}_{1}\right)
$$
$$
=\det\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{a}_{1}\cdot\mathbf{a}_{1} & \mathbf{a}_{1}\cdot\mathbf{a}_{2} & \cdots & \mathbf{a}_{1}\cdot\mathbf{a}_{k}\\
\mathbf{a}_{2}\cdot\mathbf{a}_{1} & \mathbf{a}_{2}\cdot\mathbf{a}_{2} & \cdots & \mathbf{a}_{2}\cdot\mathbf{a}_{k}\\
\vdots &  & \ddots & \vdots\\
\mathbf{a}_{k}\cdot\mathbf{a}_{1} & \mathbf{a}_{k}\cdot\mathbf{a}_{2} & \cdots & \mathbf{a}_{k}\cdot\mathbf{a}_{k}
\end{bmatrix}\text{ by eq. (3.2)}
$$
This definition is essentially the same as the definition in [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782180/geometric-algebra-getting-the-geometric-interpretation-of-k-blades#comment7788984_3782180) by [mr_e_man](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/472818/mr-e-man).

That said, I think there is some language towards the end of 3.1.3
of GACS which is misleading, if not outright incorrect; and that may
have led to the OP's confusion. It states “We know...that the $k$-volume
associated with a $k$-blade $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{a_{1}}\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathbf{a}_{k}$
is proportional to the determinant of the matrix $[[\mathbf{A}]] =[[ \mathbf{a}_{1}\cdots\mathbf{a}_{k}]] $.
...$\left\Vert \mathbf{A}\right\Vert ^{2}=\det\left([[ \mathbf{A}]] ^{T}[[ \mathbf{A}]] \right)$,
you can...simplify this to $\det\left([[ \mathbf{A}]] \right)^{2}$.
So indeed, for $k$-blades, we do compute the squared $k$-dimensional
hypervolume.” But as the OP points out, if $k<n$, then $[[\mathbf{A}]]$
so defined is not a square matrix, so that $\det[[ \mathbf{A}]] $
is not even defined, so this discussion does not apply.
As an aside,
“is proportional to” is a bit vague - assuming the determinant
is nonzero, every number (of the same sign?) is proportional to it.
I think the intent might have been for a factor of $\pm1$ only.

Here is another equivalent definition of norm that is
more explicitly coordinate-based: The standard basis (or your favorite
basis)$\mathbf{e}_{1},\ldots,\mathbf{e}_{n}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
gives a basis for $\bigwedge\mathbb{R}^{n}$ along the lines of $\left(1,\mathbf{e}_{1},\ldots,\mathbf{e}_{n},\mathbf{e}_{1}\wedge\mathbf{e}_{2},\mathbf{e}_{1}\wedge\mathbf{e}_{3},\ldots,\mathbf{e}_{\left(n-1\right)}\wedge\mathbf{e}_{n},\mathbf{e}_{1}\wedge\mathbf{e}_{2}\wedge\mathbf{e}_{3},\ldots\right)$.
Then the norm of a $k$-blade (or any multivector that is a sum of
various blades) can be expanded in terms of this basis of $\bigwedge\mathbb{R}^{n}$
with a finite collection of coefficients. Analogous to the norm in
$\mathbb{R}^{n}$, we can then define the norm to be the square root
of the sum of the squares of these coefficients. This expression for
norm is Definition 6.10 in LaGA.

Finally, the *first* definition of norm of a blade in LaGA is Definition
6.8, which requires writing the blade in a special form, using Gram-Schmidt
or similar. If we have nonzero orthogonal vectors $\mathbf{b}_{1},\mathbf{b}_{2},\cdots,\mathbf{b}_{k}$, then
“the *norm* of the blade $\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{b}_{1}\mathbf{b}_{2}\cdots\mathbf{b}_{k}$
is $\left|\mathbf{B}\right|=\left|\mathbf{b}_{1}\right|\left|\mathbf{b}_{2}\right|\cdots\left|\mathbf{b}_{k}\right|$.
This is the volume of the rectangular parallelogram with edges $\mathbf{b}_{1},\mathbf{b}_{2},\ldots,\mathbf{b}_{k}$.”

#### Orientation

In the table referenced in 2.8.2 of GACS, they write that the (relative) orientation
is “the sign of the weight relative to $\mathbf{I}$” “where
$\mathbf{I}$ is a selected standard subspace with the same attitude”.
When $n=k$, we have a conventional standard choice for $\mathbf{I}$:
e.g. $\mathbf{e}_{1}\wedge\mathbf{e}_{2}$ or $\mathbf{e}_{1}\wedge\mathbf{e}_{2}\wedge\mathbf{e}_{3}$,
where $\mathbf{e}_{i}$ are standard basis vectors. But if $n>k>0$,
there's not really a canonical choice; so for a given $k$-dimensional
subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ you'd have to make a somewhat arbitrary
choice for $\mathbf{I}$. But, no matter what, you could still determine
whether two blades with the same attitude/subspace had the same orientation
or opposite orientations. Section 6.2 of LaGA says “A positive (respectively
negative) scalar multiple [of a blade] retains (respectively reverses)
the orientation of the subspace.”

Comment: If the downvoter would like to comment about what is lacking or could be improved with this answer, I would be happy to receive criticism either in public or in private via the email in my profile.

Comment: I apologize for not having given a feedback on your answer yet. It's not an easy subject for me and I'm studying several sources on it. So I need the right time to fully examine your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Giovanni No worries. Take your time and let me know if there's anything you would like me to clarify.