Given $A = (e_1 + e_2)$ wedge $(e_2 + e_3)$, example gives Norm(A) $= 2$, yet I get $\sqrt3$. Can I get help?
Working through "Geometric Algebra for Computer Science: An Object Oriented Approach" on my own. The problem comes from an example on page $130$. This should be an easy calculation, why I'm all the more frustrated.
Calculating it using the general formula (see image) I get the wrong answer.

I do understand how to get $2$ by just multiplying the lengths of the vectors on either side of the wedge product, since the vectors are orthogonal, i.e., (left side) dot (right side) $= 0$. But want to understand where my mistake is in above calculation.
Thanks for your help!

Welcome to MSE. Please post your question with all the supporting details so that we do not have to click on a link please. As specified in the MSE Guidelines [tour].

This is still unclear, too much shortcuts in your worksheet.

They're not orthogonal. The dot product is $(e_1+e_2)\cdot(e_2+e_3)=1$. The norm is $\sqrt3$.

For any multivector $$A=a+b_1\mathbf e_1+b_2\mathbf e_2+b_3\mathbf e_3+c_1\mathbf e_2\mathbf e_3+c_2\mathbf e_3\mathbf e_1+c_3\mathbf e_1\mathbf e_2+d,\mathbf e_1\mathbf e_2\mathbf e_3$$ where $a,b_n,c_n,d$ are scalars, the norm is easily calculated as $$\lVert A\rVert=\sqrt{a^2+b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2+c_1^2+c_2^2+c_3^2+d^2}.$$ I'm not sure if you're supposed to learn this earlier or later in the book. -- See also my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3198338/inner-product-structure-on-geometric-algebra

The close votes are completely unwarranted. The question is as clear as it could possibly be.

Great, thanks @mr_e_man for confirming and pointing out the mistake on orthogonality. Much appreciated!

@NicholasTodoroff: I didn't down-vote, but it's possible such down-votes are based on the mathematics being included as an image as opposed to being typeset. I don't agree with that, but it does happen.

As mr_e_man says, the vectors are not orthogonal,
$$
  (e_1 + e_2)\cdot(e_2 + e_3) = e_1\cdot e_2 + e_1\cdot e_3 + e_2\cdot e_2 + e_2\cdot e_3 = 0 + 0 + 1 + 0 \ne 0
$$
and $\sqrt3$ is correct.

This doesn't effect your final answer, but you're missing a minus sign. The inner product with a vector is an antiderivation, you have to grade-reverse the factor it "passes over":
$$
  v\cdot(A\wedge B) = (v\cdot A)\wedge B + \color{red}{\hat A}\wedge(v\cdot B).
$$
So you should have
$$
  e_2\cdot(e_3\wedge e_2) = \color{red}-e_3.
$$
Somehow you magically bring the minus sign back in the end though.

A much easier way is to just use $v = e_1 + e_2$ and $w = e_2 + e_3$ directly:
$$
  A\cdot\widetilde A = (v\wedge w)\cdot(w\wedge v) = v\cdot[w^2v - (w\cdot v)w] = w^2v^2 - (w\cdot v)^2 = (2)(2) - (1)(1) = 3.
$$

Excellent, good to know my calculation was correct. The orthogonality and missing the negative (when scalar is on right of wedge) were silly mistakes.  Thank you for showing me a better way to calculate, treating vectors as fundamental things rather than going straight to components.  I need to get in the habit of think like that.  Much appreciated!

@Mark the negative has nothing to do with "where the scalar is"; perhaps you just mean this as a sort of mnemonic, but I would avoid that sort of thinking. This is purely a result of how the dot product and wedge product interact. The wedge product is commutative on scalars ($A\wedge 1 = 1\wedge A = A$ for all $A$) and if say $A$ is a bivector then we have no minus sign in the following: $$e_1\cdot(A\wedge e_1) = (e_1\cdot A)\wedge e_1 \color{red}+ A.$$

Oh, somehow I had it, A wedge k = - k wedge A, due to the anticommutavity of the wedge product.  Thank you!

@Mark It is only guaranteed to be anticommutative between two vectors. It then follows that if $A$ is a $k$-vector and $B$ is an $l$-vector that $$A\wedge B = (-1)^{kl}B\wedge A.$$ You prove this by assuming $A, B$ are blades (which you can do because $\wedge$ is bilinear) and then anticommuting all the vector factors past each other as needed.
